# Pass a lambda expression in place of iComparator in VB.Net

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I have the following C# expression

```
var orderedMatches = matches.OrderBy((t1, t2) => t1.Item1 - t2.Item1).ToList();
```

And am trying to translate to VB with Option Strict On, most translators produce something like below

```
Dim orderedMatches As List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String)) = matches.OrderBy(Function(t1 As Tuple(Of Integer, String), t2 As Object) t1.Item1 - t2.Item1).ToList()
```

Or just below and neither one compiles.

```
Dim orderedMatches As List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String)) = matches.OrderBy(Function(t1, t2) t1.Item1 - t2.Item1).ToList()
```

I have tried multiple converters and also setting Option Strict Off and setting T1 and T2 to Object.
The usual error is

```
BC36532 Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'Func(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String), Object)'
```

OrderBy is defined as

```
Public Shared Function OrderBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IOrderedEnumerable(Of TSource)
```

or

```
Public Shared Function OrderBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey), comparer As IComparer(Of TKey)) As IOrderedEnumerable(Of TSource)
```

I need to code to compile with errors preferably with Option Strict On

Comment: What type is matches and Item1? Usually the queries are simpler in VB.NET than in C#. I don't understand the minus operation, is this just an integer operation or an overloaded operator of the Item1? Without these details I would suggest ```(from e in matches order by e.Item).ToList()```

Comment: Matches is a List of Tuples containing an Integer and a string. The integer is actually a location and the goal is to sort the list of strings by location. The minus is being used to compare the integers. Item1 is the integer in the Tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in VB.NET is like this:

```
Dim orderedMatches = matches.OrderBy(Function(x, y) x.Item1 - y.Item1).ToList()
```

although your sort logic is buggy and crashes in my example with Int32.MinValues and Int32.MaxValues because of arithmetic overflows. A solid implementation could look like this:

```
Dim orderedMatches = matches.OrderBy(Function(x, y)
                                            If (x.Item1 < y.Item1) Then Return -1
                                            If (y.Item1 < x.Item1) Then Return 1
                                            Return 0
                                        End Function).ToList()
```

Both examples above only work if there is somewhere an OrderBy extension method defined and imported (in C# as well as VB.NET), that works like this:

```
<Extension>
Public Module BubbleSortLambda

    <Extension>
    Public Function OrderBy(Of T)(collection As IEnumerable(Of T), logic As Func(Of T, T, Int32)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        If (collection Is Nothing) Then Throw New NullReferenceException() 'To simulate instance method behavior
        If (logic Is Nothing) Then logic = Function(x, y) 0
        Dim myComparer As New GenericComparer(Of T)(logic)
        Dim myArray As T() = collection.ToArray()
        Array.Sort(myArray, myComparer)
        Return myArray
    End Function

    Private Class GenericComparer(Of T)
        Implements IComparer(Of T)

        'Private Fields
        Private ReadOnly _SortLogic As Func(Of T, T, Int32)

        'Constructors

        Public Sub New(sortLogic As Func(Of T, T, Int32))
            If (sortLogic Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(sortLogic))
            _SortLogic = sortLogic
        End Sub

        'Public Methods
        Public Function Compare(x As T, y As T) As Int32 Implements IComparer(Of T).Compare
            'Handle null
            If (x Is Nothing) Then
                If (y Is Nothing) Then Return 0
                Return -1
            End If
            If (y Is Nothing) Then Return 1
            'Invoke logic
            Return _SortLogic(x, y)
        End Function

    End Class

End Module
```

Comment: The code comes from Roslyn and I have included the reference in my VB code. I think what I missed is to get it to work is I must use a multiline Lambda Function which you provided. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Cohen: Which namespace / NuGet is it? I didn't find it in the normal 4.7.2 framework where all the other OrderBy extension methods are defined.

Comment: It is in the source of Roslyn, not .net Framework. They are a lot of OrderBy functions.

Comment: And which one? Roslyn is big. I intend to use this sort function in future, I like its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Hint: Would be usually done in the project settings...
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Module StartUp

    Public Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim matches = GenerateData()
        Dim orderedMatches = (From e In matches Order By e.Item1).ToList()
        orderedMatches.ForEach(Sub(x) Console.Out.WriteLine(x))
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

    Private Iterator Function GenerateData() As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Int32, String))
        Yield Tuple.Create(100, "Hundred")
        Yield Tuple.Create(1, "One")
        Yield Tuple.Create(Int32.MinValue, "MinValue")
        Yield Tuple.Create(Int32.MaxValue, "MaxValue")
        Yield Tuple.Create(0, "Zero")
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Yes you solved the sort in a very elegant way but did not answer the question. I am trying to figure out how to create the "comparer As IComparer(Of TKey)" in VB that compiles.

Comment: I tried to figure out what your C# line does but I cannot compile ```var orderedMatches = matches.OrderBy((t1, t2) => t1.Item1 - t2.Item1).ToList();```. Where is this extension method defined which takes two elements t1 and t2 for bubblesorting?

Comment: The code is used here ..\Roslyn\src\Test\Utilities\Portable\MarkedSource\MarkupTestFile.cs and defined ..\Repos\Roslyn\src\Compilers\Core\Portable\InternalUtilities\EnumerableExtensions.cs